# Get IProject in PropertyPage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating an eclipse PropertyPage. In the property, I would like to get the users project. In order for the user to get to the property, he must right click the project and click properties. So I am assuming it is possible to get the users project. Can you get the users project in a PropertyPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getElement()` method of `PropertyPage` returns the selected object for the property page. So use something like:

```
IAdaptable adaptable = getElement();

IProject project = (IProject)adaptable.getAdapter(IProject.class);
```

Do this is the `createContents` method, the element is not yet available in the constructor.

Comment: Interesting.. why is this not available in the constructor?

Comment: Because it is set by a call to `setElement` after the page has been constructed.